# Modifying the speed of music playback in android

Tags: android, audio, playback

The Media class doesn't have function which allows the needed functionality.

Does a better way exist to change the music speed?

Comment: Hi Mehran how did you solve this issue.Can you share with me I am looking for same functionality in my app.

Comment: I decided to drop it because there is no easy way to do it(at least when I asked the question, I have't checked recently). Depending on what you want to do you could have multiple speeds prerecorded and play them back accordingly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately MediaPlayer does not allow it. You can vote for this feature to be included in Android by default here: http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=1961

The best apps that support it that I found are ACast (which has very good support for downloading podcasts, which is mainly where I use it to speed up audio files) and Astra Nova Player (which could be your replacement for MediaPlayer entirely).

I hope this helps.

Comment: How can I use those functionalities in my app.

Comment: Unfortunately, I've since moved away from Android, so would not know how it evolved.