# How to change playback rate of music in Android?

Tags: android, android-mediaplayer

Hi I am working on an music app for Android.In that I want to change playback speed & reverb value for music dynamically.
In my view there will be two `SeekBar` for both playback speed & reverb value, so on changing `SeekBar`'s value sound must change accordingly.

Currently I am using `MediaPlayer` but after search I found the MediaPlayer doesn't support functionality for changing playback speed.
Then I tried with `SoundPool`, with this I am able to changes the speed of track.But with `SoundPool` I am not able to use the big music files.

I want a way where I can change both speed & reverb value.

I am searching for weeks for solution but still I am not able to find it.
Please please help me...

EDIT

```
float playbackSpeed = 1.5f;
    SoundPool soundPool;
    int soundId;

    void soundPooler()
    {

        soundPool = new SoundPool(4, AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC, 100);

        final int soundId = soundPool.load("/storage/sdcard0/Music/departed.mp3", 1);
        AudioManager mgr = (AudioManager) getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);
        final float volume = mgr.getStreamMaxVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);

        soundPool.setOnLoadCompleteListener(new OnLoadCompleteListener()
        {

            @Override
            public void onLoadComplete(SoundPool arg0, int arg1, int arg2)
            {
                soundPool.play(soundId, volume, volume, 1, 0, playbackSpeed);

            }
        });
    }
```

This is the code I have tried.
Thanks..

Comment: this might answer your question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5149050/changing-the-speed-of-music-playback-in-android

Comment: Hi Daniel I checked your link but it is not what I am looking for.

Comment: I love the title of this question :)  I suggest taking your android device outside the earth's atmosphere.  In the atmosphere you have a static speed of about 340 m/s.

Comment: i do not understand why you are not able to use `SoundPool` for big music file. could you explain more?

Comment: @blganesh101 I don't know why it is not playing big files.

Comment: could you add the code. Ideally it should work smoothly with  `SoundPool`.

Comment: @blganesh101 Can you help me setting reverb values with SeekBar?